# Suppressing ArcGIS Pro will expire in X days warning?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-license-manager

Upon starting ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 at a client's site today I am receiving a warning:

```
ArcGIS Pro
Pro Advanced will expire in 15 days
```

[image]

It looks like the licenses (which are issued from an ArcGIS Portal) will expire on 30 June 2017, and I am confident that the site will renew them.

If the message were coming from ArcMap I would use [C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/administer/advanced-arcmap-settings-utility.htm) to suppress it.

Is there an ArcGIS Pro means to do the same?

I would have expected to find it on the Licensing tab of the Project page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started ArcGIS Pro 2.2.1 today, I saw the dialog below.

[image]

It looks like there is now a simple checkbox to Show license expiration warning messages that can be unticked.